# Linq - Excluding items from different list types

Tags: vb.net, linq

Is there any way to select items in a list that aren't contained in another? For example:

```
list1 = From t In list1 Where Not list2.Contains(t.column1)
```

That gives me the error:

```
Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to '<anonymous type>'
```

which makes sense, since list2.Contains is expecting the same type as list2. However, the list types are different. I want only to select based on column comparisons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
list1 = From t In list1 Where Not list2.Any(l => t.column1 = l.column1 AndAlso t.column2 = l.column2)
```

I am unsure how efficient it would be, but I think it should work for you.

Comment: I love how elegant that is and I think it's almost there. But I'm getting this exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[ToolObject]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ToolObject]'."

Comment: Throw a .ToList() onto the end? (with parenthesis around the entire statement)

Answer (score 7):

Look at the .`Except()` extension method, combined with a projection:

```
list1 = list1.Except(list2.Select(Function(l) l.ID))
```

Comment: Except still expects a list of the same type for comparison.

Comment: Then use a projection to map it: list1.Except(list2.Select(...) )

Comment: Is there a way to do this with multiple columns?

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer satisfies the original requirement that it's t.column1 which specifies the part of the list1 element to be excluded.

Answer (score 7):

Well what does `list2` actually contain? If you can express your query precisely, we can probably express it in LINQ. Without knowing what `list1`, `list2` and `column1` are it's hard to help.

What I *would* say is that `List<T>.Contains` is going to be O(n) for each item you check. If `list2` is potentially non-small, you may well want to create a `HashSet<T>` - then each `Contains` call will be a lot faster.

But then again, when we know more about the situation we may well suggest a completely different solution. Please make the question as concrete as possible to get the best answer.

EDIT: If tvanfosson's solution works for you *and* if you're using LINQ to Objects, you've got a potential performance pit there. It would be better (IMO) to do the projection on `list2` *once* and build a set:

```
Dim invalid = New HashSet(Of Integer)(list2.Select(Function(x) x.Id))
list1 = From t in list1 Where Not invalid.Contains(t.column1)
```

Comment: As usual, Jon Skeet for the linq win ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created this extension method:
Notice that the second sequence can have different type, however you have to specify the key and optionally the comparer.

```
  public static IEnumerable<TOuter> Except<TOuter, TInner, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer, IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
        Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector, Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
     IEnumerable<TOuter> iguales = outer.Join(
        inner           : inner,
        outerKeySelector: tOuter => outerKeySelector(tOuter),
        innerKeySelector: tInner => innerKeySelector(tInner),
        resultSelector  : (o, _) => o,
        comparer        : comparer);
     return outer.Except(iguales);
  }
```

Here's how you can use it

```
     String name = "John";
     Char[] chars = { 'h', 'n' };
     var result = name.Except(
        inner           : chars,
        outerKeySelector: c => c,
        innerKeySelector: c => c); // result will contain J, o
```