# How to use IsNot in Linq Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a dropdownlist that populates the list of Field1(Id) from Table1(Which has list of Ids) which comes from one entity framework. Table2 also have (Ids) which are from Table 1 that are already used from other entity framework. . So my current dropdownlist should display the ids from both the tables that are not used. My scenario is if one Id is selected and create button is clicked that id should not be seen again in the dropdown list.But i want to filter the values by using the below query but result of below query is not giving any values into the dropdown list. I am very new to VB.Net. Can anyone help me with this.

LINQ Query

```
Dim weTypeQry1 = (From x In db.Table1 _
                          Where x.field1 Select
                           x IsNot
                          (From y In db1.Table2
                           Where y.feild2 = x.field1
                            Select y)).ToList()
```

Comment: You need to use [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You mean in the place of 'IsNot' - 'Except' (I did try didnt work)

Comment: No! If you think that you can simply replace `IsNot` with `Except`, i have to say: it's not working that way. Follow above link.

Comment: Save yourself the troubles and use a [**linq join**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx)

Comment: Your question is not clear and you didn't improve it by adding sample data and expected output. I removed my answer because all you said about it was: "isnt working". Well, I can't make it "working" if you don't clarify what you try to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Query for this..Below link helped a lot

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877738/linq-excluding-items-from-different-list-types

 Dim weTaskTTQry = (From x In db1.Table1 _
                             Select x.Field1).Distinct.ToList()

Dim weTypeQry1 = db.TAble2.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(p) Not (weTaskTTQry.Contains(p.Filed2))).ToList()
```